Linux command to replace placeholder in one file using value from another file
I have env.config file containing environment variables, and app.config file for my application config. I want to copy values from env.config and paste them in app.config.
I tried to use both awk and sed but I'm not very good with linux command. Can someone please show me how to do it?
Thanks.
Note: I don't want to use source env.config as that might try to execute env file as a shell script.
env.config file:
....
....
Environment=Development
AppName=MyApp
....
....

app.config file:
....
....
logName = logs/{AppName}/{Environment}
....
....

The final output in app.config should look like this:
....
....
logName = logs/MyApp/Development
....
....

UPDATE
I apologize for not mentioning that I need to replace only those 2 variables mentioned above. I don't need to extract the other variables present in the env.config file. But I see a lot of you guys provided your solutions for extracting all the variables. Thank you all for your time!
Eventually I figured out and I'll post my answer so that someone else can benefit from it later. I'll post it here since the question has been marked as duplicate.
# Grab AppName and Environment variables from env.config
APP=`grep AppName $"env.config" | awk -F= '{print $2}'`
ENV=`grep Environment $"env.config" | awk -F= '{print $2}'`

# Put the environment variables in app.config
sed -i "s/{AppName}/$APP/" app.config
sed -i "s/{Environment}/$ENV/" app.config


your approach is pragmatic for a small number of variables known in advance. for efficiency, you can combine the two sed so you only overwrite the file once. note that in the general case (maybe not yours): /, \1 (or any backslash), &, etc, in replacement values may make sed fail or cause mangled output; and unintended expansions can happen if expanding one keyword produces something that looks like another one (eg. {{app}} -> {env} or {app} -> blah {env} blah)

@jhnc I didn't know I could combine two sed commands. Thanks, will give it a try!

While Python is usually more verbose than awk and sed for this kind of tasks, it is not different from those in what concerns that it can be called as a one-liner directly from the shell.
and it happens to be the language I know.
So, this command on the shell will perform what you need, provide your files don't contain any exceptions to what you list. It gains a lot  in this case, given that the syntax you picked for your template file is the same used by Python's str.format method:
python -c "open('output.config', 'wt').write(open('app.config').read().format(**dict([tuple(line.strip().split('=') ) for line in open('env.config') if line.strip()])))"


I come up with a solution for bash.

Isolate all the variable assignment line on the env.config file, source them each separately in shell for later use.

for i in  $(cat env.config| egrep "^.+=.+$"); do source <(echo $i);done


Isolate all the variable assignment line on the env.config file again, but this time instead of sourcing them, put the variable names to an array.

array=($(cat env.config| egrep -o "^.+=.+$"| egrep -o "^[^=]+"))


Now go through the array element by element, if the variable name strings exist in other app.config file, replace them with the values of  said variables, which were assigned in first step.

for i in "${array[@]}"; do sed -iE "s/{$i}/${!i:-\0}/g" app.config; done


did you read the part in the question where using source was rejected? consider what your code does if env.config contains a line: foo=bar;date

Even the array solution suffers from inadeqate quoting; you want for i in "${array[@]}" with double quotes. Also probably lose the useless cat

@tripleee thanks for pointing out the error. I corrected the quoting issue in edit. But keeping the cats as personal preference.

awk
awk '
    BEGIN { ORS=""; FS="{" }
    NR==FNR {
        if ( i=index($0,"=") ) {
            key = substr($0,1,i-1)
            value = substr($0,i+1)
            a[key] = value
        }
        next
    }
    {
        print $1

        for (f=2; f<=NF; ++f)
            if ( i=index($f,"}") ) {
                key = substr($f,1,i-1)
                rest = substr($f,i+1)
                print ( key in a ? a[key] : FS key "}" ) rest
            } else print FS $f

        print RS
    }
' env.config app.config

For each env file line, look for =. If found, extract key-value pair and add to lookup table.
Unset ORS to disable default trailing newlines.
For each app file line:

print first field (i.e. part before before first {)
for each remaining field:

if it has matching }

try to substitute the key


else reinsert { (and maybe } too) and print as-is


print trailing newline


A slightly different approach, more like the Perl version at the end:
awk -v ORS= '
    NR==FNR {
        if (i=index($0,"="))
            a[substr($0,1,i-1)]=substr($0,i+1)
        next
    }
    {
        for (s=$0; match(s,/{[^{}]+}/); s=substr(s,RSTART+RLENGTH)) {
            key = substr(s,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)
            print( key in a ? substr(s,1,RSTART-1) a[key]  \
                            : substr(s,1,RSTART+RLENGTH-1) )
        }
        print s RS
        next
    }
' env.config app.config

Scan env file as in first version.
For each app file line:

for each template variable found:

if it can be replaced:

print up to the start of the match, then print the replacement
else print up to end of the match location


extract the new tail of the line


print the tail

perl
perl -nle '
    @ARGV ? /^([^=]+)=(.*)/ && ($a{$1}=$2)
          : print s|{([^{}]+)}| $a{$1} // $& |erg
' env.config app.config


@ARGV is 1 while reading first file; 0 while reading second file
bool ? y : n is ternary operator, similar to awk
-n adds implicit loop over each line of input
for each line of first file:

if line conforms to regex, store extracted parts in lookup table


for each line of second file:

run s command (s|regex|cmds|flags)

g - "global" - look for all matches
e - execute RHS as command(s) to produce replacement string
r - return modified string instead of count of changes
for each regex match:

return lookup ($a{$1}) if defined else (//) return match unchanged ($&)




print possibly modified line



bash
A pure Bash 4 / Bash 5 approach:
#!/bin/bash

declare -A a
declare -n m=BASH_REMATCH

loadvar(){ [[ $2 =~ ^([^=]+)=(.*) ]] && a["${m[1]}"]=${m[2]}; }
mapfile -t -c1 -Cloadvar <env.config

expand(){
    q=$2
    #               (m1                      )(m4          )(m6)
    #                                             (m5    )
    while [[ $q =~ ^(([^{}]*}?)*([{]?[^{}]*)*)([{]([^{}]+)})(.*) ]]; do
        printf '%s%s' "${m[1]}" "${a["${m[5]}"]:-"${m[4]}"}"
        q="${m[6]}"
    done
    printf '%s' "$q"
}
mapfile -c1 -Cexpand <app.config



define shortcut variable m - typing BASH_REMATCH is tedious
use mapfile to run callback function on each line of file
loadvar - same idea as all other programs
expand:

split line into prefix, key, suffix
attempt to substitute, with fallback if not found (${var:-default})
chop off prefix and template
loop until no more matches
print the tail



sample
env.config:
....
Environment=Development
AppName=MyApp
....

app.config:
unchanged
normal:     logName = logs/{AppName}/{Environment}
nested:     {{AppName}} / {{AppName}:{Environment}}
unbalanced: AppName}}}{{{{Environment}
unbalanced: {AppName}}}}{{{Environment
undefined:  {hello}

result:
unchanged
normal:     logName = logs/MyApp/Development
nested:     {MyApp} / {MyApp:Development}
unbalanced: AppName}}}{{{Development
unbalanced: MyApp}}}{{{Environment
undefined:  {hello}

Only replace specific keywords
All the above can be modified to only replace specific keys.
For example:
For awk, create a master lookup of keywords and only store those.
A different array can be used if absence of definition in env file should result in no change
(instead of replacement with empty string):
BEGIN{ split("Environment AppNAme", a) }
...
            if (key in a) a[key] = value
...

For Perl or bash, the regex could be modified directly:
^(Environment|AppName)=(.*)

